# How to store data in field from database in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logic

I have a problem which is related to logic than a technology, here is a scenario, (I am using Spring + Hibernate)

I need to read some data from database to return back to page on every get request, but I thought some hack here that what if using some script someone reload page very frequently, this will cause that many calls to server, for this I thought to read data and put them in global variables or class variable, by doing so i end up writing very weird code many global variable and stupid way to give them initial value like for a variable user-status which is a byte type variable I have given -2 as initial value so that my inner logic can understand no value is set for this variable from database, below is my code

```
    @Controller
    /* @Secured("hasRole('ROLE_USERS')") */
    @RequestMapping("member")
    public class ApplyRoles {

        @Autowired
        private UserInformationForAccessApplication checkUserStatus;

        // we will initialize variables to avoid auto-initialize by constructor
        private byte userStatus = Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.GLOBALINIT,
                requesttype = Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.GLOBALINIT,
                access = Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.GLOBALINIT;

        Map<String, Object> accessnrole;
        Map<String, String> country;
        Map<String, String> roleArray;

        @Autowired
        StudentEnrollmentApplication enrollmentApplication;

        @Autowired
        SystemProperties systemProperties;

        @Autowired
        EmployeeEnrollmentApplicationResume employeeEnrollmentApplicationResume;

        @Autowired
        AccessEnrollmentProcessing accessEnrollmentProcessing;

        private String role = Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.ROLENOTSET,
                fname, lname;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String checkingUserStatus(Model model, HttpSession session,
                Authentication authentication) {

            String sessionemail = "yashprit@gmail.com";// (String) session
            // .getAttribute(Constant.SessionAttributes.LOGGEDINUSER);

            // first check global value, if found set than don't fetch from database
            if (userStatus == Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.GLOBALINIT) {
                // get user status from MySQL Database
                userStatus = checkUserStatus.checkStatus(sessionemail).get(0);
                if (!(userStatus == Constant.UserRoleApplicationStatus.NOTAPPLIED)) {
                    access = checkUserStatus.checkStatus(sessionemail).get(1);
                    model.addAttribute(Constant.SystemName.ACCESS, access);
                }
            }

            if (!(userStatus >= Constant.UserRoleApplicationStatus.NOTAPPLIED || userStatus <= Constant.UserRoleApplicationStatus.REJECTED)) {
                model.addAttribute("error", "User status is not avaible");
                return "redirect:error/pagenotfound";
            } else if (userStatus == Constant.UserRoleApplicationStatus.NOTAPPLIED) {
                if (requesttype == Constant.IntializationOfGlobalVariable.GLOBALINIT) {
                    // get request type from MongoDB database
                    requesttype = checkUserStatus.getRequestType(sessionemail);
                }

                if (!(requesttype == Constant.RequestType.NORMALEBIT || requesttype == Constant.RequestType.INVITEBIT)) {
                    model.addAttribute("error",
                            "Facing Technichal Issue, Please try again");
                    return "redirect:error/pagenotfound";
                }

                if (requesttype == Constant.RequestType.INVITEBIT) {
                    if (!(Byte.parseByte((String) accessnrole
                            .get(Constant.SystemName.ACCESS)) == Constant.Access.USERBIT)) {
                        accessnrole = checkUserStatus
                                .getAccessAndRole(sessionemail);
                    }

                    if (accessnrole.get(Constant.SystemName.ACCESS).equals(
                            Constant.Database.ERRORMESSAGE)
                            || accessnrole.get(Constant.SystemName.ROLE).equals(
                                    Constant.Database.ERRORMESSAGE)) {

                        model.addAttribute("error",
                                "Facing Technichal Issue, Please try again");
                        return "redirect:error/pagenotfound";
                    }

                    model.addAttribute(Constant.SystemName.ACCESSNROLE, accessnrole);
                    model.addAttribute(Constant.SystemName.REQUESTTYPE, requesttype);
                }
            }

            model.addAttribute(Constant.SystemName.USERSTATUS, userStatus);


            return "member/user";

        }
}
```

to avoid global variable i thought of suing cookies, because I don't want to call database on every page reload in same session, once its loaded for a session than I don't have to call to database.

Anything that can help to to redesign above part of code is much appreciated

thanks

Comment: That is entirely the wrong level to be trying to defend against a DDOS attack.  If your java application server is exposed to the public internet it should be proxied behind apache, and apache should be defending it from that.

Comment: @Affe I agreed to you on Apache(web server) should handle this kind of nonsense but this is also related to performance let say, User is reloading page every 2 min, i think Apache should not have any problem with this kind of behavior. I am going through ehcahe whats you take on that, caching result using ehcahe, serving them through cache once written. is caching mechanism like Ecache is session dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are thinking about is called a "cache". It is a standard Computer Science way of doing things and they have been doing research on how to use caches for as long as there have been computers.

You might want to go do some reading on the subject. I found this one by Googling "cache tutorial java" http://javalandscape.blogspot.com/2009/01/cachingcaching-algorithms-and-caching.html

In simplest terms (a one item cache) what you want is to store some data object that you recently took some time to come up with. But you also have to have some sort of identifier so you can tell if the next request is asking for the same data. If it isn't, you have to do all the work over. If it is the same data, you just return it again.

So the algorithm works something like this in this simple case:

```
if (storedData != null && storedRequestInfo == userRequest.requestInfo) {
    return storedData;
}

storedData = youCalculateTheRequestedData();
storedRequestInfo = userRequest.requestInfo;

return storedData;
```

Its not any real programming language, just something to show you how it works.

The requestInfo is whatever comes in with the request that you use to look up your database stuff. You save it in storedRequestInfo after any calculation.

This shows it as returning some data to the user, that's what is in storedData.

It's a simple, one-element cache.

(To expand on this, you can store the storedRequestInfo and storedData in the session and you end up with one of these stored for each user. You can also use a java Map and store a bunch of storedData. The problem is to decide how to limit your memory use. If you store too many of these for each user, you use up too much memory. So you limit how many each user can have either by size or by count. Then you have to decide which one to delete when it gets too big. In the simple case, you always delete, in essence, the stored one and store a new one.

I noticed your comment. ECache is just a big fancy Map in the terms I used above. I don't know if it's naturally session dependent but it can be made that way by adding the session id to the cache key.)

Comment: thanks, just after starting this question I come to know about Ehcache, is there any other tool available in java for cache dependent on session or any blog/URL from where I refer to. At the end of day configuration in java biggest thing to do.

Comment: How many different instances of the same thing do you think you will need to store for any single user? If its usually only one, just have a 'last one' in the session. In that case, a true cache is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

There are really 2 things that you are considering, and correctly me if I'm wrong, but:

1. Caching on the server (in your Java application) to avoid doing a database lookup multiple times for the same data.
2. Avoid the client (browser) from sending multiple requests to the server.

The first can be resolved using caching which is available in spring uses annotations on any given method. The documentation is available [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

The second is a bit more tricky and I' leave it for now unless you discover a performance problem. It's again possible to do in Spring and takes advantage of the HTTP protocol and caching controls available in the HTTP header to inform the browser how long to cache responses.

Comment: You got me correct point is what I am thinking of now. But bit interested in learning more about point 2, I didn't get it, could you please share some URL on you point 2.

Comment: See this http://www.i-develop.be/blog/2010/07/30/spring-mvc-3-0-http-cache-control-headers/